# How can I reverse the order of headings in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, styles, headers

I have a Word 2013 document with a few dozen headings arranged in chronological order.

```
# 2017
   ## ...
   ## October
   ## November
   ## December
# 2018
   ## January
   ## February
```

I am looking to reverse the heading order so that these dates are sorted from newest to oldest.

```
# 2018
   ## February
   ## January
# 2017
   ## December
   ## November
   ## October
   ## ...
```

**How can I reverse the order of headings in a Microsoft Word document?**

Answer (score 2):

I can't verify in Word 2013, but if the function isn't there, you could open it in someone else's Word 2016 for one of these solutions:

A) Manually drag-and-drop from the Navigation pane
[Navigation Pane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZOoa.png)

B) Sort using Outline View

```
1. Enter Outline View (View: Outline), collapse any headings you don't want sorted.
2. Enter Home Tab, Select everything you want sorted, Paragraph: Sort, Choose Heading Dropdown and asc/descending
```

[Outline View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEwZL.png)
[Sort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyHey.png)

C) Macro (only worth writing if you need to do this often)